# Can I deploy a slug to heroku without including the runtime

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, slug

I'm trying to follow this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-deploying-slugs?preview=1 to create a slug of my node app and deploy to heroku. Given that heroku has a nodejs buildpack built into it I can't help thinking there must be a way to do so without including the node runtime as recommended, but it's not easy to find out how in the platform api docs.

Anyone have an ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can also create slugs programmatically using the Build API. See these guides

- [Building and Releasing using the Platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-and-release-using-the-api)
- [Programmatic builds on Heroku](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/5/21/introducing_programmatic_builds_on_heroku)

This is also mentioned in the intro to the article you mentioned, but I'll make that clearer.

Feel free to get in touch at friis@heroku.com if you have any questions about how to use this.